# Static Routing - host to host ping does not work (MikroTik)?

Tags: routing, router, ip, ping, icmp

I'm trying to do static routing using actual devices. Below is my setup:

[image]

The left router is a **MikroTik RouterBoard hAP lite**.

The right router is a **MikroTik RouterBoard hAP ac**.

I want to ping from laptop to laptop.

I configured static route on both routers. Here's the routing table:

[image]

[image]

It works fine on packet tracer.

But in actual, I can ping every address from each laptop except the other laptop.

Both laptop have gateways.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: For a device to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer that. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 2):

Static route configuration in both R1 & R2 router configuration is correct . According to your configuration should be able to establish connectivity among both laptop s without any issues.

1. check whether gateway is reachable from laptops , verify it by pinging gateway from laptop .
2. check ARP table in router whether Mac address of laptop is visible with ip address of laptop

`Sh ip arp | i 192.168.88.252`

3. Check connectivity from router whether 192.168.77.254 is reachable from router1 ,Verify it with pinging from router1.

If it's real time please  verify  firewall status on laptop end . If it's windows laptop please ensure windows firewall is off.

Comment: "ensure windows firewall is off" should really be "ensure windows firewall permits ICMP echo". Never switch off a local firewall permanently.

Comment: If end point antivirus like macafee , Escan or any other antivirus is install at PCs then window firewall can switch off ..